# How expose javascript variable with Rails 6?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have in javascipt/pack a *home.js* file

```
var hello = "hello"
window.hello2 = "hello"
```

But, after loading the view associated (home.html.erb), in the javascript console of my navigator for these variables I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined` or `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `var hello = "Hello"` - When you type `> hello` in console, this will not work because of a concept called Closure in Javascript. I found [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-closure-b2f0d2152b36) helpful.
2. `window.hello2 = "Hello"` -> You are assigning a global variable. When you type `> window.hello2` in console it will give the output, but just `> hello2` won't work and it gives `ReferenceError`.

   - `window.hello2` is available to all your JS code, it is global.
   - However, it's not recommended to use global variables, use vars in respective functions.

Also, you didn't mention that how you're using your `pack/home.js` file.

If you include `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home' %>` in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`, then your JS code will run in every controller/view(not just in `Home` controller.)

If you include `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'home' %>` in `app/views/home/index.html.erb`, then your JS code will run in only in `home#index` action - but it triggers refresh.